# Yes/no user prompt to continue or stop the script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this nice Google Apps Script that works fine, but it results in the deletion of a sheet in my Google spreadsheet thus I would like the script to start with a Yes/No prompt asking "Are you sure you want to close the job". If he says yes, great, go on; if not, exit the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found this

```js
// Display a dialog box with a message and "Yes" and "No" buttons.
// The user can also close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert(
    'Are you sure you want to continue?',
    ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO
);

// Process the user's response.
if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    Logger.log('The user clicked "Yes."');
} else {
    Logger.log(
        'The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.'
    );
}
```